# How to Find each & every room's latitude and longitude inside Organization/Office in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geolocation, xamarin.android

I am working on location based android application using Location Manager & Geo Fencing. Below are the scenario/Example for my implementation.

- In our Home/Organization we have total no of 10 Rooms. When a user enter into different Rooms need to notify the Admin User about user changing the Room. The same is achieved by using android Geo-Fencing .

As mentioned in [Google Geofencing](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)  as , 
**"For getting best results from your geofences is to set a minimum radius of 100 meters"** for single Geo-Fencing.

In our scenario inside the organization , a room to another room distance may be below 1 meter as well. Here I have some questions regarding Geo-Fencing as ,

1. How can we use Geo-Fencing in each room.?
2. The Lat/Long values are differeed in last 2/3 decimal digit values in every room. So how can we get every rooms accurate lat/lang?
3. How can we use multiple Geo-Fencing (10 rooms) inside the organization within one meter distance because of the Android Geo-Fencing min required radius of 100 meters for best result as mentioned in above link?

Note: Inside room GPS is not working . So we have used the Network provider. We can't get accurate location(Lat/Long) values in Network Provider.

So could you please provide the roadmap or solution for achieve the above.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: consider upvote / accept the helpfull answer(s)

Answer (score 0):

The only relible indoor locationing are iBeacons or similar devices. That are low energy blue tooth devices delivering an beacon id, and the estimated distance to that beacon.

You can install one in each room.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion AlexWien.  Is there any other way to acheive the same  by using other API's without using external devices installation (like iBeacon)?

Comment: The other known but not stable technology is the analysis of the magnet fields in the building. There is even an App on the App Store for that technic. Smartphones today have a 3d magnet sensor built in (for compass). I would not recommend thi stechnic if you want a working comercial and reliable system.